# Hodgkin huxley neuron not spiking consistently for currents greater than threshold?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, action-potential

Hi I am currently studying physics at the undergraduate level. As part of my final year project Ive got to implement the HH model and investigate certain types of behaviour.

My issue is the following.

I understand that for $I_{inj}>I_{thresh}$ we should expect action potentials that spike at a regular frequency.

[image]
Here I've got an input current that seems to generate 2 initial spikes however no further spikes are generated. Is this physical? The presence of the initial spikes must mean that the input current is greater than the threshold, but we do not see consistent spikes across the entire stimulatory current.

Increasing the current slightly gives the expected behavior:
[image]

Is this an error in the code or is this a real physical phenomena?

EDIT------------------------------
Following Bryan Krause's suggestions, here is the full picture with the gating variables.

Case 1:
Stimulus current with amplitude 35 mA with period 100ms
[image]

Case 2:
Stimulus current with amplitude 37 mA with period 100ms
[image]

Case 3:
Stimulus current with amplitude 500 mA with period 100ms
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: @tyersome I believe I have shown my attempt at an answer  by providing the second example as going by the HH model, that is what I believe should have also been observed in case 1.

Comment: What are the equations this model is solving?  Your case 1 looks like a strongly damped oscillator in the voltage, whereas case 2 looks like an oscillating solution. If you have a nonlinear damping constant, that could explain the difference between case 1 and 2 qualitatively.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape The [HH model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodgkin%E2%80%93Huxley_model) is quite a famous standard model in neuroscience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening due to sodium channel inactivation. Some relevant sources:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_and_chain_inactivation

[https://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/~wjh/hh_model_intro/](https://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/%7Ewjh/hh_model_intro/) (I guess this link is broken for some people? works fine for me as-is; see the links before and after instead, then)

https://neuronaldynamics.epfl.ch/online/Ch2.S2.html

In the [HH model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodgkin%E2%80%93Huxley_model), inactivation is sometimes referred to as the "h-gate" based on the parameter they use for this inactivation, assigned the variable "h".

Sodium channel inactivation changes the action potential threshold and can even prevent action potentials completely. The easy way to understand this is that inactivated channels aren't available to participate in the positive feedback loop of an action potential. Because of this, it's not quite correct to think of a constant threshold for action potentials for a given cell/model. Instead, there is a threshold for any given holding potential or recent history of the membrane potential. Most often, you'll be concerned with the threshold at the resting membrane potential, but if you apply a constant external stimulus (or if you trigger a lot of action potentials in sequence without enough time spent at hyperpolarized or resting potentials) then the number of available sodium channels is not the same as at rest.

I would suggest a couple things...first, try other steps, too! What happens if you use an *even bigger* stimulus? Second...plot out the HH gating parameters m, n, and h as a function of time, not just the voltage.

Comment: Ive added a few more cases to my original question. Based on your answer I can't understand why case 3 and case 1 look identical.

Comment: @Vishal Look at the h-gate! Compare h before the first stimulus to after the first action potential (or first couple, once the APs stop).

Comment: Your St. Andrews link is dead.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Works fine for me.

Comment: I cant access the St. Andrews link either…

With regards to the h gate behaviour, I can see that h is quite close to 1, which makes sense since the neuron is hyper polarised. I’m not sure what to take away other than h is high when the neuron is hyperpolarised and low when the neuron is depolarised.

Comment: @VishalJain h is only close to 1 at rest; later in the pulse, it is less than 1. In the first case, it's low enough that the threshold has shifted so the stimulus is no longer superthreshold after the first spike, and h continues to decrease (more inactivated).  In the second case, there is enough of a relaxation of the h gate during the hyperpolarization between spikes. In the third case, the stimulus is too strong and the h gate never has a change to reopen; h stays low and so there are not available sodium channels to open.

Comment: I don’t get why the neuron seems to come to a resting potential at V = 0 after the first spike in case 1, but got case 2 (with just a small increase in the injected current), the neuron properly hyperpolarises in between action potentials. 

Looking at the gating variables values all make sense when you look at the corresponding membrane potential at that time step.

EDIT: reading the previous comment it seems as though that tiny increase in current was enough to give the h gate enough time to relax to properly reset?

Comment: @VishalJain It's not just the membrane potential that matters, but also the state of all the gating parameters. In both case 1 and case 2, there is never a time that the h gate makes it all the way back to 1; it looks like it recovers to around 0.9 in both case 1 and case 2. Case 2 has a strong enough stimulus to still trigger an AP with only 90% of the channels available; case 1 doesn't, but the subthreshold depolarization is sufficient to cause even more channel inactivation (h continues to decrease over time).

Comment: Ok it’s starting to make sense, last question on this and I think it’ll click.

I can accept that in case 1, we provided a stimulus that was super threshold when the cell was at rest, however once stimulated it was no longer large enough to generate further spikes.
However,  if you look at my original image where i provided an image where we had 2 such initial spikes, how can you explain this? Here we clearly simulated the cell once when it was at rest in a hyper polarised state and again once while the stimulatory current was being applied, however then we stopped generated spikes.

Comment: @VishalJain You can see in your "case 1" that there is kind of a mini-spike; it's enough for some voltage gated channels to open and depolarize the cell a second time, but not enough for a full positive-feedback spike. By the third such "event" it's even weaker. Same thing happened in your original case 0 except the stimulus was strong enough to make the second spike, but you do see that the second AP is a little weaker than the first, and the third fails. All of this is best understood by thinking about how many sodium channels are available, aka "not inactivated", aka "h".